# AWS IAM Role - AccessDenied error in one pod

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-iam, k8s-serviceaccount

I have a service account which I am trying to use across multiple pods installed in the same namespace.

One of the pods is created by Airflow KubernetesPodOperator.
The other is created via Helm through Kubernetes deployment.

In the Airflow deployment, I see the IAM role being assigned and DynamoDB tables are created, listed etc however in the second helm chart deployment (or) in a test pod ([created as shown here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/eks-pods-iam-role-service-accounts/)), I keep getting `AccessDenied` error for `CreateTable` in DynamoDB.

I can see the AWS Role ARN being assigned to the service account and the service account being applied to the pod and the corresponding token file also being created, but I see `AccessDenied` exception.

```
arn:aws:sts::1234567890:assumed-role/MyCustomRole/aws-sdk-java-1636152310195 is not authorized to perform: dynamodb:CreateTable on resource
```

**ServiceAccount**

```
Name:                mypipeline-service-account
Namespace:           abc-qa-daemons
Labels:              app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=Helm
                     chart=abc-pipeline-main.651
                     heritage=Helm
                     release=ab-qa-pipeline
                     tier=mypipeline
Annotations:         eks.amazonaws.com/role-arn: arn:aws:iam::1234567890:role/MyCustomRole
                     meta.helm.sh/release-name: ab-qa-pipeline
                     meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: abc-qa-daemons
Image pull secrets:  <none>
Mountable secrets:   mypipeline-service-account-token-6gm5b
Tokens:              mypipeline-service-account-token-6gm5b
```

P.S: Both the client code created using `KubernetesPodOperator` and through Helm chart deployment is same i.e. same docker image. Other attributes like `nodeSelector`, `tolerations` etc, volume mounts are also same.

The `describe pod` output for both of them is similar with just some name and label changes.
The `KubernetesPodOperator` pod has QoS class as `Burstable` while the Helm chart ones is `BestEffort`.

Why do I get `AccessDenied` in Helm deployment but not in `KubernetesPodOperator`? How to debug this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever we get an `AccessDenied` exception, there can be two possible reasons:

1. You have assigned the *wrong role*
2. The assigned role doesn't have necessary *permissions*

In my case, latter is the issue. The permissions assigned to particular role can be sophisticated i.e. they can be more granular.

For example, in my case, the DynamoDB tables which the role can create/describe is limited to only those that are starting with a specific *prefix* but not all the DynamoDB tables.

> So, it is always advisable to check the IAM role permissions whenever
> you get this error.

As stated in the question, be sure to check the service account using the `awscli` image.

---

Keep in mind that, there is a credential provider chain used in AWS SDKs which determines the credentials to be used by the application. In most cases, the `DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain` is used and its order is given below. Ensure that the SDK is picking up the intended provider (in our case it is `WebIdentityTokenCredentialsProvider`)

```
 super(new EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider(),
              new SystemPropertiesCredentialsProvider(),
              new ProfileCredentialsProvider(),
              WebIdentityTokenCredentialsProvider.create(),
              new EC2ContainerCredentialsProviderWrapper());
```

Additionally, you might also want to set the AWS SDK classes to DEBUG mode in your logger to see which credentials provider is being picked up and why.

---

To check if the service account is applied to a pod, describe it and check if the AWS environment variables are set to it like `AWS_REGION`, `AWS_DEFAULT_REGION`, `AWS_ROLE_ARN` and `AWS_WEB_IDENTITY_TOKEN_FILE`.

If not, then check your service account if it has the AWS annotation `eks.amazonaws.com/role-arn` by describing that service account.